# Index of Data after train and test split

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science, train-test-split

guys, I'm new to Data science and Python. I'm working on a regression problem. My question is when I'm trying to plot my test part of target variable im getting strange type of plot

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_input, test_input, train_target, test_target = 
train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)
# Remove the labels from the dataset
plt.xlim(0,100)
plt.plot(test_target , 'g');
```

[image]

is it because of random indexes attached to test_target..?

how can i get continous curve like this [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If index of the data is the problem then use:

```
df_train = df_train.reset_index()
```

If you want to reset and set it to another column of df lets say "A" then do:

```
df_train = df_train.reset_index().set_index('A')
```